# scipy.optimize.leastq Minimize sum of least squares

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I have a least squares minimization problem that has the following form

[image]

Where the parameters I want to optimize over are `x` and everything else is known.

[scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) has the following form:

```
scipy.optimize.least_squares(fun, x0)
```

where `x0` is an initial condition and `fun` is a "Function which computes the vector of residuals"

After reading the documentation, I'm a little confused about what `fun` wants me to return.

If I do the summation inside `fun`, then I'm afraid that it would compute RHS, which is not equivalent to the LHS (...or is it, when it comes to minimization?)

[image]

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: The documentation says you are permitted to return an array of shape (m,) (where m is the number of dimensions of the output of the function). It isn't necessary to return a scalar.

Comment: Ah I see - so, since my vectors `ji` and `bi` are fixed parameters, I can simply return a vector of `||ji - Q(x, bi)||^2` for `i=1` through `i=n` ?

Comment: From an example in the documentation: "Notice that we only provide the vector of the residuals. The algorithm constructs the cost function as a sum of squares of the residuals, which gives the Rosenbrock function." So it looks like those details are handled for you. You only need to give the residuals as such.

Comment: I think I can move forward now, thank you! If you want to post this as an answer I’d be glad to mark it as such.

Comment: Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) of `scipy.optimize.least_squares`, the argument `fun` is to provide the vector of residuals with which the process of minimization proceeds. It is possible to supply a scalar that is the result of summation of squared residuals, but it is also possible to supply a one-dimensional vector of shape (`m`,), where `m` is the number of dimensions of the residual function. Note that squaring and summation is not done in this instance as `least_squares` handles that detail on its own. Only the residuals as such must be supplied in this instance.